# T-test of two groups of a 15 groups experiment

Tags: anova, t-test, multiple-comparisons

I'm a biologist, so for most of you my question is gonna be the dumbest one. I made an experiment with triplicates and performed anova and tukey's test, but the later was not significant. What I would like to know is if I perform a T-test between to groups of samples (different treatments) I will be forcing a different result. Why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It will be hard to give a good answer without having more details on the nature of your measurements and which hypotheses that you were trying to test with the experiments. Some types of data are better handled with some type of transformation before running anova, etc. Also, if you had a specific hypothesis about differences between 2 particular groups from the beginning before you ran the experiments on all the groups, that's different from testing for differences between groups that you discovered in your analysis of the results of the experiments.

Comment: Sure! I am evaluating if there is any difference in a product yield of fermentation according to enzyme doses. I have 15 treatments with triplicates for each one. Firstly, I tried an ANOVA followed by Tukey's test, but it was not significant. After, I thought to use T-test between 2 treatments that I've considered important, but it sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Are these 15 different enzymes, 15 different "doses" of the same enzyme, or some combination of different enzymes and doses? What controls are there?

Comment: These are a combination of different doses and enzymes (14 treatments + 1 gold standard enzyme + dose as "control")

Comment: Was the ANOVA itself significant (e.g., F-test)?

Comment: The ANOVA was significant. I used R and agricolae package for HSD Tukey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a significant *F*-test in ANOVA, you have reason to believe that there are some significant differences among the treatments. So you can proceed with testing of between-treatment differences.

Your choice of the [Tukey test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tukey%27s_range_test) for between-teatment differences might have been OK if you had no idea which comparisons you cared about, but that's not the case here. You have a "gold standard" treatment as a control, and what you presumably care the most about is whether any of the other treatments are better than that gold standard and thus are worth pursuing in detail as a replacement. That is comparing multiple treatments against a single control, for which the classic test is [Dunnett's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett%27s_test).

The advantage of Dunnett's test could be dramatic in this situation with 15 treatments in total. In correcting for the multiple comparisons being made, Tukey's test has to take into account all the possible ways you could do pairwise comparisons among 15 treatments: 105 comparisons. To avoid Type-I error for this whole family of 105 tests, Tukey's test thus requires a very large difference to claim "significance." In Dunnett's test you are only making 14 comparisons against the single control, so smaller differences can be deemed "significant" than in the Tukey test with the same protection against Type-I error. My guess is that Dunnett's test might provide defensible "significant" findings with your data.

It also matters how you are intending to use the results of these experiments. If you are using these results to guide follow-up studies better to document and explore the advantages of some new enzyme or dose, then you could just consider this work a pilot study, not worry excessively about statistical significance at this point, and depend on later, more detailed experiments to document both the practical and statistical significance of the new treatment(s) of interest. If you are instead intending to publish these results on their own, then ANOVA followed by appropriate multiple testing is required. One might, however, then wonder about why you didn't further pursue the interesting leads suggested by these initial experiments.

For your specific question about separating out specific *t*-tests, if you really, truly and honestly had one particular combination of new enzyme and dose that you wanted to compare against the "gold standard" before you did the experiments, or a small number of such pre-defined comparisons among treatments, then you might be OK in doing  *t*-tests for those particular comparisons (with a Bonferroni or other correction for multiple testing with more than one comparison). But if the results of these experiments in any way informed your choice of which comparisons to make, then you need to use an appropriate multiple-comparison test.

Going forward, consider this as an example of how a larger experimental design is not always better when you have to take multiple comparisons into account.

Comment: I did not use Dunnet because it's not a true control, I mean the gold standard uses different types of enzymes than my treatments. In addition, the "control" passes by a pretreatment that the others conditions don't. Could I still use Dunnet?

Comment: @user2501348  It doesn't matter whether the "gold standard" is a "true control" or not. What matters is the structure of the comparisons that are important to you. If you want to see whether any of the new treatments differs from the "gold standard," then Dunnett's test with the "gold standard" as reference makes sense. If you want to examine all 2-way comparisons of the 15 treatments, then Tukey's or some similar test is required. That decision has to be based on your (and your reviewers') understanding of the underlying subject matter.